# c++ http tcp server to server connection

Tags: c++, network-programming

I am trying to turn the server/client model into a server/server model, so as to have the my 2 computers running the program find each other by perhaps a url or something else like ip address.I was wondering if it was possible for 2 servers to connect via url's. or is ip the only way? examples would be appreciated since this is my second day writing c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTTP, the server only talks to clients. So, I am not sure what you mean by server to server.

URLs are fine to use to access an HTTP server, but the host name will need to be resolved into an IP address before a network connection can actually be established. You should be able to find libraries that will do those details for you, but it is not hard to manually establish a socket connection to an HTTP server.

There are configurations where there are multiple servers, acting as a single server. These are sometimes referred to as web farms or a HTTP cluster. Typically, there is some sort of load balancer in front of the cluster. Many HTTP load balancers support a server affinity feature to make sure a client is sent to the same server in the cluster for subsequent operations.

In a cluster configuration, servers may need to synchronize shared state, such as file system data or configuration data. This is typically handled by some mechanism that is external to the HTTP server process itself. The HTTP server process may need to cooperate with the synchronization, but this can be as simple as restarting the process.

There is another mode of HTTP server configuration called a reverse proxy configuration. A cluster of HTTP proxy servers sit in front of a single HTTP server. The proxy servers are thought to be cheap and expendable entities that off load work from the HTTP server itself, providing a scalable means to increase HTTP server capacity.

There are many open source HTTP server and proxy projects available as examples of how they are implemented. If you are trying to build your own custom server application, you can have a look at the HTTP examples in [Boost asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/sync_client.cpp).